# In which place internally java run Exceptions

Tags: java, jvm, java-native-interface

I wonder about how JVM or JDK runs exceptions. For example if we have array

`int tab[] = {1, 2, 3};`

and we try to access

`tab[10]`

JVM run `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` it's ok. Is tt possible to see in which part of JDK or JVM execution of this exception? I mean `throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException()` or something like this? Is it impossible from the call for JNI calls?

Comment: You can throw exceptions from JNI code as well: https://stackoverflow.com/q/230689/14955

Comment: This is both in the interpreter and the native code. You can use JITwatch to read the native code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25129355/3448419) for a simple overview of how exceptions work in HotSpot JVM.

As to JVM code that throws `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, there are multiple places to see:

1. Interpreter. The implementation of `iaload` bytecode in the interpreter (as well as other array access bytecodes) includes index check. If the check fails, the interpreter jumps to exception throwing stub. See [templateTable_x86.cpp](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/30a02b4e6c06/src/hotspot/cpu/x86/templateTable_x86.cpp#l769):

   ```
   void TemplateTable::iaload() {
     transition(itos, itos);
     // rax: index
     // rdx: array
     index_check(rdx, rax); // kills rbx                              --------------
     __ access_load_at(T_INT, IN_HEAP | IS_ARRAY, rax,                             |
                       Address(rdx, rax, Address::times_4,                         |
                               arrayOopDesc::base_offset_in_bytes(T_INT)),         |
                       noreg, noreg);                                              |
   }                                                                               |
                                                                                   |
   void TemplateTable::index_check(Register array, Register index) {             <--
     // Pop ptr into array                                                          
     __ pop_ptr(array);                                                             
     index_check_without_pop(array, index);                           --------------
   }                                                                               |
                                                                                   |
   void TemplateTable::index_check_without_pop(Register array, Register index) { <--
     // destroys rbx
     // check array
     __ null_check(array, arrayOopDesc::length_offset_in_bytes());
     // sign extend index for use by indexed load
     __ movl2ptr(index, index);
     // check index
     __ cmpl(index, Address(array, arrayOopDesc::length_offset_in_bytes()));
     if (index != rbx) {
       // ??? convention: move aberrant index into rbx for exception message
       assert(rbx != array, "different registers");
       __ movl(rbx, index);
     }
     Label skip;
     __ jccb(Assembler::below, skip);
     // Pass array to create more detailed exceptions.
     __ mov(NOT_LP64(rax) LP64_ONLY(c_rarg1), array);
     __ jump(ExternalAddress(Interpreter::_throw_ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException_entry));  !!!
     __ bind(skip);
   }
   ```
2. JIT compilers (C1 and C2). When a method is JIT-compiled, the compiler includes a similar index check sequence in the produced machine code. Sometimes, when a compiler can prove that no out-of-bounds condition may happen, it eliminates the redundant check.

   For example, C1 compiler first emits platform-independent range check in the intermediate representation, see [c1_LIRGenerator.cpp](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/30a02b4e6c06/src/hotspot/share/c1/c1_LIRGenerator.cpp#l478):

   ```
   void LIRGenerator::array_range_check(LIR_Opr array, LIR_Opr index,
                                       CodeEmitInfo* null_check_info, CodeEmitInfo* range_check_info) {
     CodeStub* stub = new RangeCheckStub(range_check_info, index, array);
     if (index->is_constant()) {
       cmp_mem_int(lir_cond_belowEqual, array, arrayOopDesc::length_offset_in_bytes(),
                   index->as_jint(), null_check_info);
       __ branch(lir_cond_belowEqual, T_INT, stub); // forward branch
     } else {
       cmp_reg_mem(lir_cond_aboveEqual, index, array,
                   arrayOopDesc::length_offset_in_bytes(), T_INT, null_check_info);
       __ branch(lir_cond_aboveEqual, T_INT, stub); // forward branch
     }
   }
   ```

   Then during code generation RangeCheckStub is expanded to platform-dependent assembly which includes a jump to exception throwing stub, see [c1_CodeStubs_x86.cpp](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/30a02b4e6c06/src/hotspot/cpu/x86/c1_CodeStubs_x86.cpp#l103):

   ```
     if (_throw_index_out_of_bounds_exception) {
       stub_id = Runtime1::throw_index_exception_id;
     } else {
       stub_id = Runtime1::throw_range_check_failed_id;
       ce->store_parameter(_array->as_pointer_register(), 1);
     }
     __ call(RuntimeAddress(Runtime1::entry_for(stub_id)));
   ```

   Finally this results in calling [`Exceptions::_throw`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/30a02b4e6c06/src/hotspot/share/utilities/exceptions.cpp#l133) function in JVM C++ code.

Answer (score 1):

ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is thrown by JVM. Bytecode does not check array index:

```
    int tab[] = {1};
    int x = tab[2];
```

bytecode for these 2 lines:

```
    ICONST_1
    NEWARRAY T_INT
    DUP
    ICONST_0
    ICONST_1
    IASTORE
    ASTORE 2
   L3
    LINENUMBER 26 L3
    ALOAD 2
    ICONST_1
    IALOAD   <-- we read element 1 which is out of bounds
    ISTORE 3
```

as you can see there is no index check, no exception thrown. It means it is done by JVM